# Using columns in a visual force page

Tags: salesforce, multiple-columns, visualforce

I have a record field I am for a revenue breakdown. I need my columns to look like they do in the picture, which is the  code I will display, except I need the revenue classification in the left column to be bottom in the right column.

When I try I get errors like cannot more than two child elements under page block items. [image: Example]

```
<apex:page standardController="EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c"
extensions="EventPackageRevenueBreakdownExt" standardStylesheets="true"
tabstyle="EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit"
        title="Event Package Revenue Breakdown Edit">
        <apex:pageblockbuttons >
            <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="{!$Label.Package_Save}"></apex:commandbutton>
            <apex:commandbutton action="{!SaveAndNew}"
                value="{!$Label.Package_SaveAndNew}"></apex:commandbutton>
            <apex:commandbutton action="{!cancel}"
                value="{!$Label.Package_Cancel}"></apex:commandbutton>
        </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>
        <apex:pageblocksection id="PackageEventInformationPBS"
            title="{!$Label.Package_Information}">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput"></apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock"></apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:inputfield required="true"
                value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.UnitPrice__c}"></apex:inputfield>
            <apex:inputfield required="true"
                value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.Location__c}"></apex:inputfield>
            <apex:inputfield required="true"
                value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.Name}"></apex:inputfield>
            <apex:outputfield value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.BookingPackageEvent__c}" />
                                <apex:inputfield required="true"
                value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.RevenueClassification__c}"></apex:inputfield>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
        <apex:pageblocksection title="Admin and Gratuity">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput"></apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputpanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock"></apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:inputfield required="false"
                value="{!eventItem.AdminCharge__c}"></apex:inputfield>
            <apex:inputfield required="false" value="{!eventItem.Gratuity__c}"></apex:inputfield>
        </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `pageBlockSection` is set to two columns (the default, I believe) then it lays out it's fields Left->Right, then down a row, then Left->Right again.

To push a field over , you can add an empty `pageBlockSectionItem`

You should layout out your fields like this:

```
<apex:pageblocksection id="PackageEventInformationPBS" title="{!$Label.Package_Information}" columns="2">
    <apex:inputfield required="true" value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.UnitPrice__c}"/>
    <apex:inputfield required="true" value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.Location__c}"/>
    <apex:inputfield required="true" value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.Name}"/>
    <apex:outputfield value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.BookingPackageEvent__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> <!-- empty selectItem--> <apex:pageBlockSectionItem/>
    <apex:inputfield required="true" value="{!EventPackageRevenueBreakdown__c.RevenueClassification__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>
```